# Protect HTTP request from being tamper

Tags: http, request

I'm using a public API for my web app and iPhone app. My app performs basics CRUD operations into a database.

As the client key of the API is sent in the HTTP request header, it will be easy for malicious users to dump that key and tamper datas initially passed to the request (with the Tamper Data Firefox plugin for example)

So here's my simple question : what are the best practices for being protected from this ?
How can I programmatically detect the different cheating cases before sending datas to the database ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Serving your webservice in `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP` would prevent anyone from sniffing your key on the wire.

Comment: Hi thx for your answer. Do you know if a solution exist in a programmaticaly way ? If not, is there ssl certificat at low cost ?

Comment: You can configure your server with a self signed certificate, no need to pay any money. Programatically just look the api/library you are using to call the webservice has support to do HTTPS calls, if it can do HTTP it would probably do HTTPS as well.

Comment: Effectively, the API i'm using seems to support https. I will do some tests of tampering datas just in case :) Thx for your help Nelson !

Answer (score 6):

SSL won't serve the purpose. HTTP/HTTPS requests can be tampered before it is sent to the server. The best way is to encrypt the data before the HTTP request is generated.